# Java : How to create an object in a method and use it throughout the class?

Tags: java, class, object, parameters, interface

```
public void setupPlayers() {
    System.out.println("Would you like the Code Maker to be Human or CPU? :");
    String input = mySc.next();
    if (input == "Human") {
        Player CodeMaker = new Human();
    }
    else {
        Player CodeMaker = new CPU();  
    }

public void exampleUse() {
    CodeMaker.getCode();
}
```

So I'm new to Java and not even sure if this is possible to begin with. The above code is all inside one class. `Human` is implementing the interface `Player`. I want to create an object `CodeMaker` using the class `Human` in the method `setupPlayers`, and then use this object in the method `exampleUse`. Is there a way to do this? If not can anyone think of any alternatives? Cheers.

Comment: why you are using an interface as a variable name? i didn't get the point

Comment: @fuzzy28 - as far as I understand, `Player` is and class impementing interface `Human`. Anyway, the sentence "an object Player using the Interface Human called CodeMaker" is a little bit confusing.

Comment: ^ Player is the interface, and Human is the class implementing Player.

Comment: I thought that "Human" and "CPU" would both implement "Player" ..

Comment: I've revised my question so hopefully it makes more sense now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you must mean the `Player` is the interface. And remember that if you want to compare the String, you should use `equals` method instead of `==` operator.

```
public class ClassName{
    private Player codeMaker;

    public void setupPlayers() {
        System.out.println("Would you like the Code Maker to be Human or CPU? :");
        String input = mySc.next();
        if (input.equals("Human")) {
            codeMaker = new Human();
        }
        else {
            codeMaker = new CPU();  
        }
    }

    public void exampleUse() {
         codeMaker.getCode();
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. After I added private Player codeMaker at the top it still wouldn't work, however I changed all the == for equals and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

You may store the `Player` object as an instance variable  :

```
Player CodeMaker = null;

public void setupPlayers() {
    System.out.println("Would you like the Code Maker to be Human or CPU? :");
    String input = mySc.next();
    if (input == "Human") {
        CodeMaker = new Human();
    }
    else {
        CodeMaker = new CPU();  
    }

}

public void exampleUse() {
    CodeMaker.getCode();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a class field variable (private, for good encapsulation) and use `"string".equals(object)` to check string equality ([How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/513832/1260526)).

```
private Player codeMaker;

public void setupPlayers() {
    System.out.println("Would you like the Code Maker to be Human or CPU? :");
    String input = mySc.next();
    if ("Human".equals(input)) {
        codeMaker = new Human();
    }
    else {
        codeMaker = new CPU();  
    }
}

public void exampleUse() {
    codeMaker.getCode(); // you need to define a return or consumption HERE
}
```

Maybe you should wrap `input = mySc.next()` in a try/catch like this, because input read can throw an Exception.

```
[...]

String input = null;
try {
  input = mySc.next();
}
catch(Exception ex) {
  throw ex;
}
if ("Human".equals(input) {
    codeMaker = new Human();
}

[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a member of class: `private Human CodeMaker;` and initialize it in constructor `CodeMaker = new Player();`

Don't do `Player CodeMaker = new Human();` - this should give you an error because you can't create an object of interface.

Answer (score 0):

Please, consider studying Creational Design Patterns. Java's culture is focused on organization and good architecture. You'll be certainly surprised with the world Design Patterns can give to you.